# Allow accordion to only open one at a time

Tags: reactjs, react-spring, resize-observer, react-resize-observer

I'm creating an Accordion with react spring, the accordion is ready and working fine, but I can not make it to allow the accordion to open one item at the time, right now open all the three item in the same time, I wish to be able to open only one.

here is the codesand -> https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-sun-ttix7?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Remember that your post should stand on its own merit: even if you have working code to link out to, [only add links in addition to](/help/how-to-ask) having the [mcve] code in your post. Ideally as runnable snippet, but at the very least as code that people can look at so they can answer your question, and so that future visitors can immediately tell whether their problem, that they found your post for, is the same as their own problem. Questions on SO are not just "to help you, now", they're "to help everyone with that problem, both now and in the future" =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to pull up the open state into the `App` component and and use the key or index as (open) indicator, like this:

App component

```js
function App() {
  const [openKey, setOpenKey] = useState()

  const handleToggle = key => {
    setOpenKey(openKey !== key ? key : null)
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      {data &&
        data.map(({ name, content }) => (
          <ServiceItem
            key={name}
            name={name}
            content={content}
            toggle={handleToggle}
            open={openKey === name}
          />
        ))}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

ServiceItem component

```js
const ServiceItem = ({ name, content, toggle, open }: ServiceItemProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div key={name}>
      <Item onClick={() => toggle(name)}>
        <Text className="text-15 regular laptop:text-20 laptop:regular">
          {name}
        </Text>
        <Icon className="text-15 regular laptop:text-20 laptop:regular">
          {!open ? "+" : "-"}
        </Icon>
      </Item>
      <Expandable open={open}>
        <ContentContainer>
          <React.Fragment key={name}>
            <Value>{content}</Value>
          </React.Fragment>
        </ContentContainer>
      </Expandable>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-banzai-fnncw.